# Windows Shell Script: Remove information from Diff output

Tags: windows, file, shell, diff

So, my program:

```
#!/bin/bash

OIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'

find teste1 -type f | while read -r firstResult

do

  find teste2 -type f | while read -r secondResult

   do

    firstName=${firstResult##*[/|\\]}
    secondName=${secondResult##*[/|\\]}

     if [[ "$( echo "$firstName" | tr [A-Z] [a-z])" == "$( echo "$secondName" | tr [A-Z] [a-z])" ]]; then
      echo "$firstResult" "$secondResult" >> equal.lst
     else
      echo "$firstResult" "$secondResult" >> notEqual.lst
     fi

      if [[ $firstName == $secondName ]]; then
       echo "$firstResult" "$secondResult" >> equal2.lst
      fi

   done

done

diff -2 equal.lst equal2.lst >> renamedFiles.lst
```

I am having some difficulty on the 'diff' part, as the output on the 'renamedFiles.lst' shows something like:

3d2
< teste1\TESTE.pub teste2\TEstE.pub

8d6
< teste1\TeStE2.xlsx teste2\testE2.xlsx

So my question is: How can I remove the "3d2" and "8d6" part? Is there a way for me to do so? I wanted to create a report for the differences and it would be "cleaner" if it didn't have those numbers. I know why the numbers are there but is there a way to remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the line formats to specify the exact format desired. For example:

```
diff -2 "--old-line-format=<%L" "--new-line-format=>%L" "--unchanged-line-format=" equal.lst equal2.lst
```

Results in bare output like:

```
>new line
<old line
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried your way, and read about line-format at Diff Man Page but anytime I actually try something with line-format, it just outputs what would output if it didn't have "-2". What I mean is that it is outputting a lot more than I wanted. It isn't outputting the diff from the 1st file to the 2nd file, it's outputting the diff from both of them into "renamedFiles"

Comment: I'm doing this on Linux here, so I don't know all the differences. Does your `diff` usag message say it supports the line formats?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that? Sorry, I'm completely new to this. Plus, I am using Windows :) Dunno if that makes a difference to you :P

Comment: Hey! I solved it. Read your code again and I noticed what I was doing wrong. Thanks a bunch for your help!